# django CMS page extension data duplication

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have a django CMS [page extension](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/3.2.5/how_to/extending_page_title.html):

```
class MyAppExtension(PageExtension):
    show_in_catalog = models.BooleanField()
    filters_to_show = models.ManyToManyField(Attribute)

extension_pool.register(MyAppExtension)
```

Views:

```
class MyListView(FilterView):
    .....

    def get_filterset_kwargs(self, filterset_class):
        extension = MyAppExtension.objects.get(
                                extended_object=self.request.current_page)
        attributes = extension.filters_to_show.all()
```

Now in every page I should get the attributes list. But in *Live* mode I get an empty list. When I switch to *Draft* mode, I get the attributes list as expected, like it should be.

After some messing, I discovered that `MyAppExtension.objects.all()` is duplicated for each page, with an empty `filters_to_show` list in each case.

Also, in *Live* mode when I call `MyAppExtension.objects.get(extended_object=self.request.current_page)` it has a different `pk` from when I call that in *Draft* mode. So my questions:

- What is happening?
- How can I get the correct object in *Live* mode?
- Why does every extension have a duplicate?

[image: live to draft]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cms.Page` objects exist in published and draft form, and the draft (along with all the objects associated with it) is copied to the other version in the Publish operation.

Your `MyAppExtension.objects` have `ManyToManyField` attributes. These will need to be copied too, otherwise the published version will fail - as you have discovered - to get back to these objects.

[Handling relations](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/extending_page_title.html#handling-relations) in the documentation for Page extensions explains what to do and gives an example - in brief, provide a `copy_relations()` method on the Page extension, that copies them to the new instance.

Without this method you'll find that all copy operations on the page, not just publishing, fail to copy the objects.

Comment: Yeah copy relations solved it, but note that code in cms docs wasn't correct for my case. In model class i wrote `def copy_relations(self, oldinstance, language):
         self.filters_to_show = oldinstance.filters_to_show.all()` and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```py
class PageDataExtension(PageExtension):

    category_page = models.ManyToManyField(category, blank=True)

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance, language):
        self.category_page.clear()

        for pcategory in oldinstance.category_page.all():
            self.category_page.add(pcategory)
```